# Magento 1.6 - Retrieving customer inputted custom options during add to cart (CartController.php/addAction)

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.6

Using a CartController.php override for the addAction function.

Basically I'm trying to take the custom options entered by a user, then generate a new product based off those options and add that to the cart instead. I have the first parts down, if a product doesn't have a custom attribute flagged, it gets added like normal... but if it is flagged, it creates a new product and adds THAT to the cart instead.

I am successfully generating the new product and adding it to the cart, but I'm unable to get the custom options that the customer entered.

```
$defaultprod = $product->getDefaultprod();
$prodID = $product->getId();
$prodOpt = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($prodID);

if (!$defaultprod == 1) {
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
if (!empty($related)) {
    $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
}
$cart->save();
}
else
{
          // code to create/add new product here, adding new product + adding to cart functioning, but CANNOT retrieve customer's custom attribute input
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: $product->getOptions($product) lists a whole bunch of attributes and info but not what was actually entered on the product page...

Comment: Yay... $this->getRequest()->getParams() is showing all the custom options entered, but in the order they're listed on the page rather than what $product->getOptions() lists them as. Anybody know how to link $this->getRequest()->getParams() array IDs to the custom option titles?

Comment: This would be better done in an observer, no?

Comment: I thought so, but I couldn't get any of the events to stop it from adding the original product... tried every variation of add/save cart before and after, including trying to delete the product from the cart AFTER it was saved.. no good. I'd have to bypass the addAction entirely somehow. I did a lot of searching before switching to an override, but people seem to have issues preventing the main item from being added to the cart. I've also finished linking the getParams to the getOptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I just tried successfully to:

- avoid adding the original product to the cart
- retrieve custom options that were originally posted on add to cart

**1) Create an observer**

This observes the event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add`

```
<controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
    <observers>
        <myobserver_identification>
            <class>module/observer</class>
            <method>myCustomMethod</method>
        </myobserver_identification>
    </observers>
</controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
```

**2) Add this in MyNamespace_Module_Model_Observer**

```
public function myCustomMethod() {
    $request = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest();

    /**
     * Avoid adding original product
     */
    $request->setParam('product', (bool) false);

    /**
     * Retrieve custom options posted on add to cart
     */
    $customOptions = $request->getParam('options');
}
```

Comment: I can't upvote without the reputation, but thank you so much - this fixed it and it's SO much more elegant. I have a lot to learn with Magento but this is great.

Comment: No problem for the upvote, the main things are that this helped you and that you validated my answer as being a resolution for further readers. Side note about the myCustomMethod(), one should also pass a parameter in the method definition like myCustomMethod($observer) and then use $observer->getRequest() to retrieve the $request object. The use of Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest() was to clearly "teach" (if I may) that one can retrieve the Controller from anywhere in the app using this snippet. Have fun Magentoing.